# Alpha router navigation by router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am migrating to the new router. Before, I had:

```js
this._router.navigate(['Main', 'Home']);
```

and my route config was;

```
Main (parent View)
---Home (child View)
```

Now, I have the following:

```js
{path: 'Main',  component: MainComponent, children:[
    {path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, children:[..]
    ....]
```

however, now the following doesn't work:

```js
this._router.navigate(['Main', 'Home']);
```

It doesnt throw an error or anything. What am I missing?

Comment: How about second lvl children? How do they look like? Or what about home cmp children? Can you show me?

Answer (score 1):

Navigation in the new router should work like this:

```js
this._router.navigate(['/Main/Home']);
```

Answer (score 0):

@rinukkusu answer is correct if home component doesnt have any children or any default route set for one of home's children routes.

As you have home component's children also,  you have to make sure following things,

1) you have imported **`ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`** and used it as **`directives`** metadata.

2) home component has **`<router-outlet>`** in its template.

3) you have already defined **`default route`** in one of home's children routes then its fine else  **`this._router.navigate(['/Main/Home']);`** will not work.

4) if home's children dont have default route defined anywhere then you have to use,

**`this._router.navigate(['/Main/Home/someChildPath']);`**

I hope this would help.